# CMD Batch delete folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Please help write in batch:

On disk c:\ I have folder named test;
in this folder I have subfolders with different names.
I need batch command to loop through all subfolders, and look for files named "Log" and/or "sqlite.sql"; if those files size < 0 Kb or do not exist then delete this subfolder with all files without prompt.

```
for each sub in Test
 if Isfile("Log") or Isfile("sqlite.sql") and EachFileSizes > 0 Then 
 Else
 Sub.delete
 End If
next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem depends on the place of the subfolders. If they all are directly under C:\test (just one level deep), then this is the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\test
rem Process all subfolders
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   rem Initially, set to delete this subfolder
   set delete=yes
   rem Confirm that
   for %%b in (%%a\Log %%a\sqlite.sql) do (
      set size=%%~Zb
      if !size! gtr 0 set delete=no
   )
   if !delete! equ yes (
      ECHO rd /S /Q %%a
   )
)
```

If subfolders may exist several levels deep beneath C:\test, then the solution is *much more* complicated.

Comment: Need some corrections:
1. this example do not delete subfolders, just create a list of subfolders such "rd /S /Q 'foldername'"
2. this example do not add to deletion list subs wich have log file =0 kb if there are exist another sqlite.sql file.
Logic must be If log>0 and exist sqlite.sql then leave subfolder, anotherway if log=0 or sqlite.sql or log files do not exist inside then delete.

Comment: 1. This solution not delete nor create nothing, it just _show_ final result commands. When you are satisfied with this, delete `ECHO ` part so rd commands be executed. 2. Your first request is very clear: "if thoose files size < 0 Kb or do not exist then delete this subfolder" "if Isfile("Log") or Isfile("sqlite.sql") and EachFileSizes > 0". This is a new requirement and require a different code (I'll do it when I have some time...)