# Locate / Delete specific folder by name - Batch code

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, locate

Dear StackOverflow community,

Could you please advise me with a Batch code for the following scenario:

> To find the folders named "Autoname" if they exist, and delete their
>   host folders (X), folder itself (Autoname) and all the files inside.
>
> (X )  folders may have any names
>
> The path is:  %userprofile%\AppData\Local\   -X- \   "Autoname"   \
>   folders & files.

I found [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105212/locate-and-delete-folders-with-command-prompt) and [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280815/cmd-batch-delete-folder) but it's not what I need.

---

Thank you All for your time, I especially appreciate the answer from @Compo, it is accepted as the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question now suggests that the `Autoname` directories exist any level within your temporary directory.

The following examples should be all that's required:

From a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"Dir/B/S/AD-L "%Temp%"|FindStr/IEC:"\\AutoName""'
) Do If Exist "%%~dpA" RD/S/Q "%%~dpA"
```

From the Command prompt:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %A In ('"Dir/B/S/AD-L "%Temp%"|FindStr/IEC:"\\AutoName""') Do @If Exist "%~dpA" RD/S/Q "%~dpA"
```

Comment: Compo, please see my comment with screen shots in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Compo, it works perfectly now! Thank you! How to adjust it to delete parent folder of 'Autoname' ?

Comment: You could change `"%%A"`, `"%A"`,  `"%%A\"` or `"%A\"`  to `"%%~dpA"`, `"%~dpA"`,  `"%%~dpA"` or `"%~dpA"` but I wouldn't recommend it in this case. The `%TEMP%` directory is there for a reason, and is frequently in use by running processes; it should not be removed.

Comment: _You could possibly use a condition to do so though, `) Do If Exist "%%A\" If /I Not "%%~dpA"=="%Temp%\" RD/S/Q "%%~dpA"`._

Comment: Thank you for your concern, but the %TEMP% directory is not a target, it just using by me for code verification purposes, as it's a relatively safe. The actual path is listed in the question

Comment: @Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%~dpA In ('"Dir/B/S/AD-L "%Temp%"|FindStr/IEC:"\\AutoName""'
) Do If Exist "%%~dpA\" RD/S/Q "%%~dpA"                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ******                                                                                                            Following your suggestion... but it doesn't work, neither Autoname nor parent was deleted

Comment: @Sam, I have put the information from my comments into my answer by way of edit again.

Comment: It's brilliant, exactly what I've been looking for.  Thank you for your time and effort. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: @Sam, if it is exactly what you have been looking for, then please mark the answer as accepted; thank you.

Comment: how can I do it? I don’t see that option

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /s /ad u:\sourcedir\*') do @if /i "%~nxi"=="e9" ECHO rd /s/q "%~dpi."
```

This should delete the parent of any subdirectory of the `u:\sourcedir` directory which itself contains a subdirectory `e9`. The directory names aren't magic - just what I used for testing.

Removal of the parent directory will delete all files and directories under the deleted directory.

This code will simply REPORT what it intends to do. **Once verified** you will need to remove the `echo` keyword to perform the deletion. Note that it's possible for this script line (it's intended to be invoked directly from the prompt) to generate error messages should it attempt to delete an `e9` directory that existed below a directory its already deleted. Appending `2>nul` to the line (including the leading space) should suppress reporting of such errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I exchanged an actual path to directory & subdirectory, it didn't work. Can you please see

Comment: for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /s /ad %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp*') do @if /i "%~nxi"=="Autoname" ECHO rd /s/q "%~dpi."

Comment: Sadly, "it didn't work" doesn't provide much information. I can't see what your file-structure is, nor what you have in mind. Are you running this directly from the prompt, or as a batch file, or are you trying to "click" it in some way? What does the `dir` sub-command alone show?

Comment: Magoo, please see my comment with screen shots in the question. Thank you

Comment: Please use the facility in the `edit` panel to **include** your screenshots so that others may see them in the future. In preference to screen-shots, cut-and-paste from the display (On Win10, right-click on `cmd` window, highlight and Enter to paste to clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to move ahead into PowerShell, the following might work. When you are confident that the correct directories will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Filter 'Autoname' |
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_.PSParentPath -Recurse -WhatIf }
```

Comment: Couldn't find a way to comment with screen shots, so 'Add Another Answer'. @Lit, please see it. Thanks

Comment: If you have time, I would like to know in what way "it didn't work." Was there an error message? Also, screenshots can be put into questions without reference to another site. On many corporate networks, such sites may be blocked.

Comment: Lit, thank you for advise - the comments added to the question. I don't know much about PowerShell, so just copy your code as it is and paste in PowerShell. There was no error. By 'didn't work' I meant 'Autoname' folder wasn't removed in the directory, as it supposed to be after running the code. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: It appears that it did not find any 'Autoname' directories. What is the output of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Filter '*Autoname*'`?

Comment: How can I know that?

Comment: You could know that by entering that command alone an pressing Enter.

Comment: Lit, let you know on Monday. Thanks